# Deep copying of EJB Entity beans with relations

Tags: java, orm, jpa

What I have is an entity bean e.g. `Entity` (EJB 3) that keeps same type children in an `ArrayList<Entity>`, his parent `<Entity>` and a relation to another entity `<Users>`. Users can own many Entities, and vice-versa (many to many).

What I would like to do is override `Entity.clone()` (or have a new method) to deep-copy `Entity` along with clones of `children` , belonging to the same parent and being assigned to the already existing users.

I have set up the clone method to create a clone of the `Entity` (a new Entity that is), and then fill it with clones of the `children` entities within a foreach loop.

But this gives me a concurrent modification exception and I end up with just a clone of the initial `Entity` bean without its `children`.

My question is:

Is what I want to do feasible at all or should I manage deep copying from e.g. a Facade?
If it is feasible, could you direct me please to something to read or give me a couple of hints, because up to now I do the cloning via a facade and it has become a major burden in my application.

Thanks in Advance!!

pataroulis

Answer (score 2):

Try using (from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/))

```
YourEntity clone = SerializationUtils.clone(entity);
```

You would have to make your entities `Serializable` (which you might not necessarily want, though). Also this should be done while the `EntityManager` is still open, otherwise you'd get lazy initialization exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new List, otherwise you are adding to the same List you are iterating over, hence the concurrent modification exception.

i.e.

```
Entity clone = super.clone();
clone.setChildren(new ArrayList());
for (Child child : this.getChildren()) {
  clone.addChild(child.clone());
}
return clone;
```

If you are using EclipseLink your could also use the copy() API on the EclipseLink JpaEntityManager.  You can pass a CopyGroup that specifies how deep to make the copy, and if the Id should be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with several problems if oyur entities are not detached. Also you have to clone or serilize your entities outside of transaction scoper otherwithe you'll Get DetachedEntityPassedToPersistException().
[Here is](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2012/02/release-your-entities/) more elaborated answer: .